# edit contact with ref to address causes fatal error

Tags: contacts

I recently updateted to civicrm 4.6.4 on drupal 7.38.
While entering contact data, I found when a contact has no address by its own, but a referral to another contact's address, edit using the edit button gives a fatal error.

Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference in /var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Edit/Address.php on line 363

No further info available like stacktrace,...

How to reproduce:
- create new contact
- save contact
- edit contact (this is working!)
- search for the new created contact. A list is presented with the searched contacts.
- choose edit on the end of the contact line.

inline editing while viewing a contact is still working.

Any ideas?

Johan.

Comment: I manage to create the same in Demo but I am not getting any error message - please do the same example against demo site (http://d46.demo.civicrm.org) and if you are still getting the error message please let me know how to reproduce - thanks

Comment: Hi, also for me it is not reproducable on the demo-site. As I'm not having much of an error, it's hard to debug.

Comment: did you manage to do John step's which he has given below

Answer (score 2):

John guided me to the solution: civicrm is located in Belgium where adresses should be "street number bus" and second line "postalcode city". I used the civicrm (alpha) extension "org.civicoop.streetformatnl" v1.0 to edit civicrm views. Unfortunately it is no longer compatible. If disabled, everything works fine.

Kind regards, Johan.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check that you updated correctly, and there there are no PHP files overriding the default CRM/Contact/Form/Edit/Address.php file?

There is a description of what this error means here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

(Googling for the error reveals a few example solutions.)

I've checked line 363 in the 4.6.4 codebase, but I can't see anything that would break it there: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.6.4/CRM/Contact/Form/Edit/Address.php#L363

Can you confirm what line 363 is in your CRM/Contact/Form/Edit/Address.php file?

Comment: Also check for incompatible extensions, tpl and php overrides, custom hooks, etc.

Comment: By my knowlegde, no php overriden by me (I didn't program php myself).

Comment: - By my knowlegde, no php overriden by me (I didn't program php myself).
- Address.php is exactly what it should be. Line 363 contains "))," like your link set so.